# undefined method `eager_load' when upgrading to formtastic 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.17 for this project. I plan to upgrade to Rails 4 but meet a lot gem incompatibilities, so I try to update some gem at first.
I am updating formtastic from 2.0.2 to 3.1.3.

I see a lot of deprecation warnings like this:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: input_class is deprecated and will be removed from Formtastic 4.0 (configure Formtastic::FormBuilder.input_class_finder instead (upgrade guide on wiki: http://bit.ly/1F9QtKc )). (called from _app_views_prescriptions__fields_html_haml___278490936240938991_103076320 at /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/app/views/prescriptions/_fields.html.haml:7)
```

And I followed formtastic wiki [Upgrading to Formtastic 3.1](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Upgrading-to-Formtastic-3.1) , and I added these two lines to `config/initializers/formtastic.rb`

```
Formtastic::FormBuilder.action_class_finder = Formtastic::ActionClassFinder
Formtastic::FormBuilder.input_class_finder = Formtastic::InputClassFinder
```

After that when I tried to run the rspec, it threw an error:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `eager_load' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000006306a50> ``

`` /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `eager_load' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000006459b50> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/formtastic-3.1.3/lib/formtastic/namespaced_class_finder.rb:32:in `use_const_defined?'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/formtastic-3.1.3/lib/formtastic/namespaced_class_finder.rb:69:in `<class:NamespacedClassFinder>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/formtastic-3.1.3/lib/formtastic/namespaced_class_finder.rb:24:in `<module:Formtastic>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/formtastic-3.1.3/lib/formtastic/namespaced_class_finder.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/formtastic-3.1.3/lib/formtastic/action_class_finder.rb:7:in `<module:Formtastic>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/formtastic-3.1.3/lib/formtastic/action_class_finder.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/config/initializers/formtastic.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:43:in `load'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/spec/spec_helper.rb:12:in `require'
    from /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/spec/spec_helper.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/spec/features/patient_edit_medication.feature:1:in `require'
    from /home/hegwin/Workspace/rails_projects/pharmmd/spec/features/patient_edit_medication.feature:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/hegwin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@medpro/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun' ``

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had same problem. I am using rails 5.0.0.1, ruby 2.2.4 and formtastic 3.1.4. I followed formtastic wiki - https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Upgrading-to-Formtastic-3.1 and its works perfectly. Give a shot by upgrading rails to minimum 4.0.0 and ruby to minimum 2.0.0 it may work. Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

The issue is known to the formtastic team. See issues [#1137](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/pull/1137) and [#1135](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/1135) for details. In short, a stop-gap measure is to utilize the **issue_1135** branch of the sepastian fork. Here's the Gemfile line:

```
gem 'formtastic', :git => 'git://github.com/sepastian/formtastic.git', :branch => 'issue_1135'
```

A better idea is to fork that branch to create your own repository.